# Craft login problem with memcache and ubuntu?

Tags: php, session, yii

`session_regenerate_id(): Session object destruction failed` is the error i'm receiving after attempting to log in.

I just updated to Ubuntu 16.04LTS using PHP7 and php-memcached.

Is there a fix for this in a craft version? I'm on version 2.6.2791 and this behavior is still broken. I cannot seem to find a workaround besides overwriting Yii with a workaround myself.

Comment: Any reason why you're not using the current version of Craft (which is 2.6.2993)?  2.6.2791 was released over a year ago and Craft is currently using the latest version of yii, it should already be patched when you upgrade. Voting to close this.

Comment: @RitterKnight I was unable to update directly to 2993 from 2791. I updated to 2951 and it was still occurring. I'm planning to update to 2993 after this release next week.

Comment: Did you do a [manual update](https://craftcms.com/docs/updating#manually-updating) or use the CP?  I do believe there might have been one or two updates that required a manual update.

Answer (score 1):

I saw a few work arounds for this here, hopefully it helps:
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/issues/2376

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by updating core YII functionality that was not working suddenly with Ubuntu 16.04 and the latest version of php 7.0.

CHttpSession::regenerateID changed to:

```
public function regenerateID($deleteOldSession=false)
{
    if(session_id() === '')
        session_regenerate_id($deleteOldSession);
}
```